# Tooltip for pagination buttons in DataTables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable where I have to show the tooltip on every row and in the pagination buttons as well. I have implemented the tooltip option for the rows wherever required, but not able to figure out that how do we set the tooltip for the controls like pagination buttons (Prev and Next buttons), search (textbox) and sort (dropdown) in datatables.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">      
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
$('#example').dataTable({ 
bJQueryUI: true,
retrieve: true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"}).makeEditable({"aoColumns": [
{   
    cssclass: "required" 
},
{
    cssclass: "required"
},
{
    indicator: 'Saving...',
    tooltip: 'Click to edit',  //tooltip for row
    type: 'text',
    submit:'Save'
},
{
    indicator: 'Saving...',
    tooltip: 'Click to enter age',  //tooltip for row
    loadtext: 'loading...',
    type: 'select',
    onblur: 'submit', 
    data: "{'':'Select', 'A':60,'B':12,'C':23,'D':25,'E':65}"
},
{
    indicator: 'Saving...',
    tooltip: 'Click to select',  //tooltip for row
    loadtext: 'loading...',
    type: 'select',
    onblur: 'submit',
    data: "{'':'Select...', 'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C'}"
},
{   cssclass: "required" }
]
});      
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53s39cab/) for the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you seen this thread https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25868/using-tooltips-with-datatables

Comment: Checked the link provided by you, I have already implemented the tooltip functionality on rows. But I want to implement tooltip on the pagination buttons (Next and Previous). Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tooltip I guess you mean titles? For some peculiar reason, this is not part of the native API. In my opinion, it would be obvious to include title / tooltips-options in the `language` construct ...

```js
$('.paginate_button').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        title = isNaN(text) ? text+' page' : 'Page '+text;
    $(this).attr('title', title);
});
```

Will set `title` on the pagination buttons, as "Previous page", "Page 3" etc.

```js
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr('title', 'Type here to search in the table');

$('.dataTables_length select').attr('title', 'Select number of visible rows');
```

–  for filter / search box and the length menu.

---

Place the above inside a `draw.dt` event so `title` for the control elements is updated each time the table is redrawn :

```js
table.on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('.paginate_button').each(function() {
          var text = $(this).text(),
            title = isNaN(text) ? text+' page' : 'Page '+text;
        $(this).attr('title', title);
    });
    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('title', 'Type here to search in the table');
    $('.dataTables_length select').attr('title', 'Select number of visible rows');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But there is one more problem, the tooltip stops working if I sort, edit and save the fields in the datatable, change the length of the entries and after search also. Here is the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53s39cab/1/). So basically, these functions need to be called after every event. Is this a feasible solution then?

Comment: @Alorika, Oh yes - was implicit thinking inside a draw event handler. See update ...

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider use **titleAttr:**, example:

```
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            extend: 'pageLength',
                            className: 'pageLength',
                            titleAttr: 'Search',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-search fa-lg text-success"></i>'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'copy',
                            titleAttr: 'Copy to clipboard',
                            className: 'copyButton',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-clone fa-lg text-success"></i>'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excel',
                            titleAttr: 'Copy to excel file',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-lg text-success"></i>'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            titleAttr: 'Copy pdf file',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-success"></i>'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csv',
                            titleAttr: 'Copy to csv file',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-g text-success"></i>'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'print',
                            titleAttr: 'Print the results',
                            title: '',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible',
                                stripHtml: false,
                            },
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-print fa-lg text-success"></i>',
                            customize: function (win) {
                                $(win.document.body)
                                    .css('font-size', '10pt')
                                    .prepend(
                                        '<img src="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                                    );

                                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                    .addClass('compact')
                                    .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                            }
                        },
                    ]
```