# Titles / Tooltip for pagination in DataTables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am trying to add tooltips (titles) to the pagination buttons from DataTables (version 1.10+). I thought I could just use this piece a code (with the correct id/class identifier):

```
$('.class').attr('title', 'your new title');
```

I just can't figure out which are the correct classes for a button. I identified that all buttons have the class:

```
.paginate_button
```

but that does not work. Any ideas are much appreciated ideas!

Comment: I tried to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264877/tooltip-for-pagination-buttons-in-datatables , couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `drawCallback` option for do this.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function() {
        $('.class').attr('title', 'your new title');
    }
});
```